# saving struts2 tag information in localStorage

Tags: jsp, web, struts2, tags, local-storage

I have a string that is called in a jsp page using a struts2 tag `<s:property value="list_Name" />` which displays some name and it works perfectly fine. but would there be a way to save this information directly to local storage for later displaying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind! I'm using scriptlet tags and javascript instead. I'm sure it's not the best way to do it. but it works!

```
<%@ page language="java" import="aPackage.*"%>
...
<% aObject obj = new aObject(); %>
localStorage.setItem("aVar","<%=  obj.getAVariable() %>");
...
// anything else you want to do with the item now in local storage
```

unless anybody else has a better idea, Which is probably a lot of people on here :)